# Generate an RGB colour grid

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

This! is an RGB colour grid...

[image: Basic RGB grid]

Basically it's a 2-dimensional matrix in which:

- The first row, and the first column, are red.
- The second row, and the second column, are green.
- The third row, and the third column, are blue.

Here are the colours described graphically, using the letters R, G, and B.

[image: row and column diagram]

Here's how we calculate the colour of each space on the grid is calculated.

- Red + Red = Red (#FF0000)
- Green + Green = Green (#00FF00)
- Blue + Blue = Blue (#0000FF)
- Red + Green = Yellow (#FFFF00)
- Red + Blue = Purple (#FF00FF)
- Green + Blue = Teal (#00FFFF)

## The Challenge

- Write code to generate an RGB colour grid.
- It's code golf, so attempt to do so in the smallest number of bytes.
- Use any programming language or markup language to generate your grid.
- Things I care about:

  - The result should graphically display an RGB grid with the defined colours.
- Things I don't care about:

  - If the output is an image, HTML, SVG or other markup.
  - The size or shape of the colour blocks.
  - Borders, spacing etc between or around the blocks.
  - It definitely doesn't have to have labels telling you what the row and column colours should be.

Comment: Can we output an mage object native to our language, for example a `Bitmap` object in C#?

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance sounds fine to me.

Comment: I'm waiting for the solution in [Piet](https://esolangs.org/wiki/piet)

Comment: @manassehkatz Is it just possible that hard-coding the data would be better golf than executing it?

Comment: @AJFaraday I'm not sure but I htink the color names you use are not standard. (At least they do not agree with e.g. CSS color names.) I just know that this caused some confusion in the MathJax answer, so maybe it would be worth adjusting the names in the challenge specs too.

Comment: @flawr I could spend a LOT of time finding every word to describe these primary and secondary colours. I'm more interested in the hex values, anyway.

Comment: I'm trying to do this on a TI-84. I'm only now starting to hate the screen resolution.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart The "I don't care about size or shape" point is your friend, here. They don't have to be a uniform size or shape, it could be as small as single pixels. Also, please include a photo :)

Comment: @AJFaraday You don't have to spend a lot of time (even though usually people are encouraged to spend some time writing the challenges), I just suggest using names that are widely used and not using names that are misleading. Concretely please use `red, yellow, fuchsia, lime, aqua, blue`. If you do not care about the names but just about the RGB codes you should say so in the specs. (and in this case preferably omit the color names completely.) Anything else just results in unnecessary confusion which is not in the sense of this site.

Comment: @AJFaraday oh that makes things easier.

Comment: @AJFaraday [here you go](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/183401/84303)

Comment: Not that it really matters, but I'd personally have used _cyan_ and _magenta_ instead of _teal_ and _purple_ (or anything else). As far as I know, these are the official terms used in printing or subtractive color models such as [CMYK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model).

Comment: @Arnauld if you compare your comment to the most recent one by flaws, you’ll see why I’m not changing the names of colours in this question. You’re each asking for a different set of names as the “right” ones.

Comment: Is it allowed to use a language/platform that has a predefined color palette (like PICO-8), if its colors are at least somewhat close to the spec?

Comment: I’d say that’s probably fine.

Answer (score 36):

## Bash, 44

- 2 bytes saved thanks to @NahuelFouilleul
- 2 bytes saved thanks to @manatwork

```bash
printf "${f=^[[3%dm.}$f$f
" 1 3 5 3 2 6 5 6 4
```

Here, blocks are `.` characters.  `^[` is a literal ASCII escape character (0x1b).

[image]

You can recreate this script as follows:

```bash
base64 -d <<< cHJpbnRmICIke2Y9G1szJWRtLn0kZiRmCiIgMSAzIDUgMyAyIDYgNSA2IDQ= > rgbgrid.sh
```

Comment: what the heck? please explain :)

Comment: can save 2 bytes using shell expansion `printf ${f=\\e[3%dm.}$f$f\\n 1 3 5 3 2 6 5 6 4`

Comment: This one really brightened my day, thank you!

Comment: `printf \\e[3%dm. 1'` expands to `\\e[31m.` which is the ANSI escape code for [red](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5947802/297323) and so on and `.` is the character to print.

Comment: Continuing with @NahuelFouilleul's suggestion, double quote it: `printf "${f=^[[3%dm.}$f$f␤" 1 3 5 3 2 6 5 6 4` (Where `^[` is a literal escape character=1 byte and ␤ a literal new line character=1 byte.)

Comment: If you could use extended ASCII instead of UTF 8 you could use "█" (Ascii 219) as it would be 1 byte.

Comment: You can use background colors (escape sequence start with 4 instead of 3) and spaces instead of dots to make it more block-like.

Comment: very neat :) I like the assignement of f followed by its use.

Answer (score 29):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, 43 bytes

```
00000000: be22 01b9 0100 ac8a d83c 10b8 db09 cd10  .".......<......
00000010: b403 cd10 7204 7809 b2ff 42b4 02cd 10eb  ....r.x...B.....
00000020: e2c3 0c0e 1d0e 0a1b 0d0b 91              ...........
```

**Listing:**

```
BE 0122     MOV  SI, OFFSET CT      ; load color bar table into [SI]
        LOOP_COLOR: 
B9 0001     MOV  CX, 1              ; display 1 char and clear CH (changed by INT 10H:3)
AC          LODSB                   ; load next color byte 
8A D8       MOV  BL, AL             ; move new color to BL
3C 10       CMP  AL, 010H           ; if this is third color in row: SF=0, CF=0 
                                    ; else if last color: SF=1, CF=0
                                    ; else continue on same row: CF=1
B8 09DB     MOV  AX, 09DBH          ; AH=9 (write char with attr), AL=0DBH (block char)
CD 10       INT  10H                ; call PC BIOS, display color block
B4 03       MOV  AH, 3              ; get cursor position function
CD 10       INT  10H                ; call PC BIOS, get cursor
72 04       JC   NEXT_COL           ; if not last in row, move to next column 
78 09       JS   EXIT               ; if last color, exit 
B2 FF       MOV  DL, -1             ; otherwise move to first column and next row 
        NEXT_COL:
42          INC  DX                 ; move to next column (and/or row)
B4 02       MOV  AH, 2              ; set cursor position function 
CD 10       INT  10H                ; call PC BIOS, set cursor position
EB E2       JMP  LOOP_COLOR         ; loop to next color byte 
        EXIT:
C3          RET                     ; return to DOS
        CT  DB   0CH, 0EH, 1DH      ; color table
            DB   0EH, 0AH, 1BH 
            DB   0DH, 0BH, 91H
```

This uses the IBM PC BIOS `INT 10H` video services to write the color grid to the screen.  Unfortunately the only way to write a specific color attribute requires also writing code to place the cursor in the next correct location, so there's a lot of extra code for that.

Here's the output running on an IBM PC CGA (in 40x25 text mode to make it bigger).

[image]

### TL;DR

Here's a more verbose explanation, with more detail of what some of these machine code instructions do.

#### Color table

The colors are stored as bytes in the color table (`CTBL`) with the 4-bit color value in the low nibble and a flag value in the high nibble.  A `1` in the high nibble signals the end of the row and a `9` signals the end of the list.

This is checked using a single `CMP` instruction which subtracts `0x10` from the color values and sets the result flags.  These operands are treated as 8-bit signed values, so the sign flag (positive or negative result) and carry flag (a subtractive borrow was required, meaning the color byte is less than `0x10`) are the interesting ones here.  These flags are then checked further down for the conditional logic of whether to advance the row, the column or end the program.

**Examples:**

High nibble `0` means **not** the last in the row and **not** the last in the list:

- `0x0C - 0x10 = 0xFC` -- Result is negative and a carry (borrow) was required

High nibble `1` means it **is** the last color in the row and **not** the last in the list:

- `0x1D - 0x10 = 0x0D` --  Result is positive and no borrow

High nibble `9` means it **is** the last color of the list:

- `0x91 - 0x10 = 0x81` --  Result is negative and no borrow

#### Cursor movement

Using the PC BIOS or DOS API for output, the function that allows setting a character color does not automatically advance the cursor, so that has to be done by the program.  The cursor position must be fetched each time since the registers are overwritten later by the other functions.  The "get" function puts these into the 8-bit registers `DL` for the column, and `DH` for the row.  These same registers are what is used by the "set" function to move the cursor to a new location.

We can take advantage of the fact that, on x86 architecture `DH` and `DL` can be manipulated as a single 16-bit register (`DX`).  To advance to the next column, we increment `DX` which effectively only increments `DL` (column position).  To advance to the next column we would need to instead increment the row number and set the column to `0`.  We can do this in only one additional instruction by setting the low nibble (`DL`) to `0xFF` and then continuing the normal program flow incrementing `DX`.  Since we're now looking at `DH`/`DL` as a 16-bit value, `DL` becomes `0` and the carry from `0xFF + 1` is added to `DH`.

**Examples:**

Advance to next column:

```
DH   DL   DX
 1    1   0101   ; at row 1, column 1
 1    2   0102   ; add one to DX
```

Advance to next row, first column:

```
DH   DL   DX
 1    2   0102   ; at row 1, column 2
 1   FF   01FF   ; +set DL to 0xFF
 2    0   0200   ; add one to DX
```

Comment: Will this work in dos, prib not but would be cool if it did.

Comment: @marshalcraft Yes, in fact this will only work in DOS, or using a DOS emulator such as DOSBox, pcjs.org, etc. I've added a link to download the executable so you can give it a try.

Comment: Windows comes with limited dos emulator, probably now called command prompt, which I probably should have said, would be cool if it worked with cmd or PowerShell haha.

Comment: @marshalcraft You are correct, however since it's for DOS it's a 16-bit executable, and if you have a 32-bit version of Windows it should actually run as it has a 16-bit runtime environment. However a 64-bit edition of Windows won't run it as it only has a 32-bit runtime.

Comment: God this is a cool answer

Answer (score 25):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 41 bytes

```
Image@Outer[Plus,#,#,1]&@IdentityMatrix@3
```

[image]

---

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 68 bytes

Mathematica has built-ins for all these colors.

```
Image@{{Red,Yellow,Magenta},{Yellow,Green,Cyan},{Magenta,Cyan,Blue}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

## 80386 machine code, IBM PC DOS, 38 bytes

hex:

```
B0 13 CD 10 68 00 A0 1F 66 C7 06 00 00 28 2C 24
00 66 C7 06 40 01 2C 30 34 00 66 C7 06 80 02 24
34 20 00 CD 16 C3
```

asm:

```
mov al,13h
int 10h ; initialize vga 13h mode (320x200x256 colors)
push 0a000h
pop ds ; push video buffer address to ds
mov dword ptr ds:0, 242c28h ; print 3 pixels
mov dword ptr ds:320, 34302ch ; print 3 pixels
mov dword ptr ds:640, 203424h ; print 3 pixels
int 16h ; wait for any keypress
ret ; exit to os
```

scaled output from dosbox:

[image]

Comment: Note that `mov al, 13h` is incorrect unless it is guaranteed by DOSBox to have `ah = 0` at the program entrypoint.

Comment: @MargaretBloom [ax is 0](https://www.pcjs.org/blog/images/DOS_COM_Startup_Registers.pdf) at start of com application in ms dos

Comment: Thanks Iłya, that's good to know!

Answer (score 19):

## Excel VBA (Immediate Window), 80 bytes

```
For i=1To 9:Cells(i Mod 3+1,(i+1)/3).Interior.ColorIndex=Mid(673486857,i,1):Next
```

## Excel VBA (Function), 96 bytes

```
Sub g()
For i=1To 9
Cells(i Mod 3+1,(i+1)/3).Interior.ColorIndex=Mid(673486857,i,1)
Next
End Sub
```

Not a horrible tool for the job... I appreciate the fact that Excel already shows a grid so it is a matter of setting the background color.

[image: Excel Colour Grid]

Credit to @Neil for suggesting I use `ColorIndex` instead of `Color` leading to a 43 byte savings.

-21 bytes thanks to @Keeta

-16 bytes thanks to @Chronocidal for suggesting the "Immediate Window"

-2 bytes thanks to @i_saw_drones

Lots of changes from my original submission :)

Comment: You could probably do better with `ColorIndex` as that's a number from 3 to 8 here, which you could encode in a string or something.

Comment: @Neil - Indeed :) I was able to get it quite a bit shorter using that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I didn't see anything that stops you from changing this to Sub F() and End Sub for more savings.

Comment: You won't need the variable name in the Next statement, either.  "Next i" becomes just "Next", saving 2 bytes.

Comment: Sub g() ||
For i=2To 10 ||
Cells((i+1)Mod 3+1,i/3).Interior.ColorIndex=Mid("0367648785",i,1) ||
Next ||
End Sub || refactor to make just one for/next loop total is 99 bytes?

Comment: @Keeta - nice tips :) I'll admit VBA is not a strong suit of mine. I just thought Excel seemed like a natural place to display a grid.

Comment: I tried deleting the space between `1To` and got an error. I'll try these out when I get done time though. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: For one more byte, loop 1 to 9 with: Cells(i Mod 3+1,(i+1)/3).Interior.ColorIndex=Mid("673486857",i,1)

Comment: In many BASIC dialects it’s not neccessary to indicate which `FOR` loop you end with `NEXT`, so you can just write `Next` instead of `Next j`, `Next i`, etc.

Comment: @dulange I think that was already commented on.

Comment: @Keeta Or change `Next j` and `Next i` to `Next j,i`

Comment: Don't make it a function, and run this in the Immediate Window to drop 21 bytes: `for i=1 To 3:for j=1 To 3:Cells(i,j).Interior.ColorIndex=Mid("367408005",i*j,1):next j,i`

Comment: You can also remove quotes from the string, VBA will coerce the number into a string automatically.

Comment: lol this answer is approaching [mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/183393/86631) but I figure what the heck, everyone deserves internet points: you can address an array of cells linearly using `[A1:C3].Cells(i)`. This iterates across then down and removes the need for `mod`s.

Comment: @ i_saw_drones - hah - I didn't realize there was another VBA answer here. I think if I make that change we will literally have the same answer? Looks like you can save a byte by removing a space `i=1To 9`.

Comment: `For i=3To 11:Cells(i\3,i Mod 3+1).Interior.ColorIndex=Mid(367648785,i-2,1):Next` for 79

Answer (score 18):

## HTML + CSS, <s>121</s> 120 bytes

Worst piece of HTML I've ever wrote.
One byte save thanks to @Gust van de Wal

```css
b{color:#ff0}a{color:cyan}i{color:lime}u{color:blue
```

```html
<pre><body bgcolor=#f0f text=red>█<b>█
█<i>█<a>█
 █<u>█
```

## HTML + CSS, 114 bytes (semi valid)

I'm putting this as semi-valid because the blue is not exactly #0000FF blue and also relies on not having clicked the link.

Thanks to @Lynn for the idea

```css
b{color:#ff0}i{color:lime}c{color:cyan
```

```html
<pre><body bgcolor=#f0f text=red>█<b>█
█<i>█<c>█
 █<a href=x>█
```

Comment: You can omit the last closing bracket in the CSS. Also, incredible (and sickening) work!

Comment: You can change the tag names to avoid the default CSS formatting, e.g. `<w>`, `<x>`, `<y>`, and `<z>`.

Comment: `<a href=x>█` will be blue by default, saving you some bytes of CSS :)

Answer (score 18):

## SVG, <s>210</s> 182 bytes

```
<svg><path d="h3v3h-3" fill=#f0f/><path d="h2v2h-2" fill=#ff0/><path d="m1 1h2v2h-2" fill=#0ff/><line x2=1 stroke=red/><path d="m1 1h1v1h-1" fill=#0f0/><path d="m2 2h1v1" fill=#00f/>
```

Since the size or shape of the colour blocks doesn't matter, quite a few bytes can be golfed off with this slightly odd layout:

[image: svg layout]

Comment: I really like the ingenuity of this solution.

Answer (score 17):

## [GFA Basic 2.02](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GFA_BASIC) (Atari ST), 48 bytes

A manually edited listing in .LST format. Includes many non-printable characters, whose codes are shown within brackets.

```
?"[ESC]c[SOH] [ESC]c[ETX] [ESC]c[ENQ] "[CR]
?"[ESC]c[ETX] [ESC]c[STX] [ESC]c[ACK] "[CR]
?"[ESC]c[ENQ] [ESC]c[ACK] [ESC]c[EOT] "[CR]
```

The operating system of the Atari ST defines [extended VT52 commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT52#GEMDOS/TOS_extensions) which are used here.

#### Output

The output is a block of \$24\times24\$ pixels (9 space characters of \$8\times8\$ pixels).

[image: output]

*<sup>screenshot from [Steem SSE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/steemsse/)</sup>*

Comment: +1 for making me all nostalgic for my trusty old ST.

Answer (score 16):

## [ditaa](https://github.com/stathissideris/ditaa), 118 bytes

```
/----+----+----\
|cF00|cFF0|cF0F|
+----+----+----+
|cFF0|c0F0|c0FF|
+----+----+----+
|cF0F|c0FF|c00F|
\----+----+----/
```

This is the output using `-E` option:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

## R, <s>89</s> <s>50</s> 48 bytes

**Newest version:**

```
image(matrix(c(6,4,5,2:4,1,2),3),col=rainbow(6))
```

Not enough elements in the vector to fill the 3x3 matrix, so it wraps around and reuses the first element.

**Old versions:**

```
image(matrix(c(6,4,5,2:4,1,2,6),3),col=rainbow(6))

image(matrix(c(3,5,6,2,4,5,1:3),3),col=c('red','yellow','magenta','green','cyan','blue'))
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: wow it's [Rainbow Six](https://rainbow6.ubisoft.com/siege/en-us/home/)!

Comment: @alephalpha Yikes, I can't believe I missed that. I went ahead and fixed the oldest version and character count

Comment: 46 bytes with ```image(matrix(c(6,4,5,2:4,1,2),3),c=rainbow(6))```

Answer (score 15):

### Factorio Blueprint String, 705 bytes

I admit, I'm just pushing the limits of what counts as a solution.

```
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
```

Produced output when placed in-game (low graphics settings used):

[image]

To prove that it is a valid solution you need to sample this grid of pixels which do match the specification exactly:

[image]

The rest of the image is classified as a border or a spacing which, as said in the question, doesn't matter.

Comment: Very unique! Love it!

Answer (score 12):

## Perl 6 (and probably similar for many languages) (31 bytes)

```
{'ÿ   ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿ  ÿ ÿÿÿ ÿ ÿÿ  ÿ'}   # replace spaces with ASCII 00
                                  # which I can't seem to enter
```

This outputs a headless TIFF file, which used to be generated by Photoshop with the file extension .raw and is presumed to be square unless otherwise specified at the time of opening.  Playing around with the color depth (if allowed) could reduce this down further.

Answer (score 12):

## ffplay (ffmpeg), 93 bytes

```
ffplay -f rawvideo -s 3x3 -pix_fmt rgb24 "data:/;base64,/wAA//8A/wD///8AAP8AAP///wD/AP//AAD/"
```

**Old**:

```
ffplay -f lavfi -i testsrc=s=3x3,geq=r=255*not(X*Y):g=255*not((X-1)*(Y-1)):b=255*not((X-2)*(Y-2))
```

Answer (score 12):

## Excel-VBA, <s>89</s> <s>73</s> <s>72</s> 70 bytes

Edit: You can use the immediate window and dispense with the `Sub`/`End Sub` to save 16 bytes:

```
For i=1To 9:[A:C].Cells(i).Interior.ColorIndex=Mid(367648785,i,1):Next
```

Original answer:

```
Sub a()
For i=1To 9
[A1:C3].Cells(i).Interior.ColorIndex=Mid(367648785,i,1)
Next
End Sub
```

This was inspired by [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)'s suggestion on [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/183352/86631) answer, and is my first submission!

Result:

[image: Result Grid]

**-2 bytes**: Removal of cell row numbers - thanks to [Taylor Scott](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61846/taylor-scott)!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully I'll learn some tricks from the masters :)

Comment: `For i=1To 9:[A:C].Cells(i).Interior.ColorIndex=Mid(367648785,i,1):Next` for 70

Answer (score 11):

### JavaScript, <s>108</s> 102 bytes

```
console.log(`%c█%c█%c█
`.repeat(3),...[...`320251014`].map(c=>`color:#`+`f0ff00f0`.substr(c,3)))
```

No snippet because this only works in a real browser console and not the snippet's console. Edit: Thanks to @AJFaraday for the screenshot. Explanation: Browsers allow the first parameter of `console.log` to include substitutions. The `%c` substitution takes a parameter and applies it as (sanitised) CSS. Each `█` block is therefore coloured using the appropriate substring of `f0ff00f0` interpreted as a three-hex-digit colour code.

[image: Example of code execution]

Comment: I don't get how this works?

Comment: @marshalcraft `%c` is used to create a format string, the arguments being CSS styles for the text after it

Comment: So this is basically like dos versions but with chrome browser?

Comment: Just curious but how did you go about finding the shortest possible chain of fs/0s to use?

Comment: @Marie I started by noting that `ff0ff` contains all the mixed colours and `00f00` contains all the pure colours. If you concatenate them you get duplicate positions for `ff0` and `f00` so you can then remove the first and last characters. I then wrote a short script to check all 7-character strings to ensure that 8 was optimal.

Comment: Gotcha, I did about the same thing except I had a 9 character solution. Just for reference, because I thought it was a neat solution, I checked with a script like this `[...new Array(2**8).map((_,i)=>i.toString("2")).filter(s=>allColors.every(c => s.indexOf(c) > -1))`

Answer (score 10):

## HTML/CSS, <s>278</s> <s>141</s> 137 bytes

```css
r{color:red}y{color:#ff0}m{color:#f0f}g{color:#0f0}c{color:#0ff}l{color:#00f
```

```html
<pre><r>█<y>█<m>█
<y>█<g>█<c>█
<m>█<c>█<l>█
```

*-137 bytes thanks to commenters, most notably @data*
*-4 bytes thanks to @Einacio*

Uses Unicode `█` (U+2588) for the "blocks", and uses CSS classes/inline style to color them.

I think the `<font>` tags could be golfed more, however changing them to a shorter tag such as `<a>` breaks the `color` attribute

Comment: Leave out `</td>`, the browser is smart enough to automatically add this closing tag

Comment: If using deprecated elements, you can also specify the background color of a cell using `<td bgcolor=#f00>`

Comment: Maybe a noob question, but can't you avoid using the table and just print the █ and go to a new line with <br>?

Comment: @frarugi87 yes - 235 total: `<span style="color:red">█<span class=a>█<span class=b>█<br><span class=a>█<span style="color:#0f0">█<span class=c>█<br><span class=b>█<span class=c>█<span style="color:#00f">█`

Comment: @ASCII-only b{color:#ff0}u{color:#f0f}i{color:#0ff}
<pre><font color=red>█<b>█<u>█
<b>█<font color=lime>█<i>█
<u>█<i>█<font color=blue>█

Comment: @ASCII-only then you can also golf out 18 bytes by using the <a> tag rather than <span> one

Comment: okidokes let's implement some golfing then

Comment: `a{color:#ff0}b{color:#f0f}i{color:#0f0}u{color:#0ff}s{color:#00f
<pre><font color=red>█<a>█<b>█
<a>█<i>█<u>█
<b>█<u>█<s>█` for 138 bytes

Comment: @GustvandeWal, why do you need the font tag anyway? you can just use a custom tag, like `<r>` and it will work just fine for one less byte (actually I think it will work better, as it is not a deprecated tag :p)
```r{color:red}y{color:#ff0}m{color:#f0f}g{color:#0f0}c{color:#0ff}l{color:#00f
<pre><r>█<y>█<m>█
<y>█<g>█<c>█
<m>█<c>█<l>█``` (I'm using `<l>` for b**l**ue to avoid the default bold style, at it looks nicer now

Comment: @Einacio, oh of course. Custom tags... `pre{color:red}y{color:#ff0}m{color:#f0f}g{color:#0f0}c{color:#0ff}l{color:#00f <pre>█<y>█<m>█
<y>█<g>█<c>█
<m>█<c>█<l>█` is another byte shorter, by the way

Comment: Adding on to @GustvandeWal's comment you should be able to -3 bytes by removing the `pre` from the CSS statement too. Or in the case of the version you currently have posted, remove the `r` from CSS and the `<r>` tag from the HTML.

Answer (score 10):

## [Octave/MATLAB](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>57 56</s> 40 bytes

-17 byte thanks to @ExpiredData! Check out their [even golfier solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/183367/24877)!

```matlab
image(reshape(de2bi(126973007),[3,3,3]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/MzcxPVWjKLU4I7EgVSMl1SgpU8PQyMzS3NjAwFxTJ9pYBwhjNTX//wcA)

Comment: Does just image work instead of imshow? Don't have a Matlab license any more and I'm on phone so can't test it

Comment: @ExpiredData Thanks a lot, that works indeed!

Comment: You can probably do this too [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/MzcxPVWjKLU4I7EgVSMl1SgpU8PQyMzS3NjAwFxTJ9pYBwhjNTX//wcA "Octave – Try It Online")

Comment: @ExpiredData ---Very nice trick, thanks a lot! :)--- why don't you post this as an own answer?

Comment: Great then here's two more bytes off [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/MzcxPVWjKLU4I7EgVSMl1SgpU8PQyMzS3NjAwFxTxxgENTX//wcA "Octave – Try It Online")

Comment: Seriously, please post this as your own answer I feel like I did a lot less than half the work:)

Comment: Ok I will do that

Answer (score 10):

## MATL, <s>44 23 21 20</s> 19 bytes

A direct port of my Octave answer with the suggestions from @ExpiredData and @LuisMendo.

```
126973007Bo7B3*e0YG
```

[try it online](https://matl.suever.net/?code=126973007Bo7B3%2ae0YG&inputs=&version=20.10.0)

Answer (score 10):

\$\Large{\mathbf{\TeX} \left(\text{MathJax}\right)},~122\,\text{bytes}\$

$$
\def\c#1{\color{#1}{\rule{5em}{5em}}}
\c{red}
\c{yellow}
\c{fuchsia} \\
\c{yellow}
\c{lime}
\c{aqua} \\
\c{fuchsia}
\c{aqua}
\c{blue}
$$

**Golf'd:**

```
$\def\c#1{\color{#1}{\rule{5em}{5em}}}\c{red}\c{yellow}\c{fuchsia}\\\c{yellow}\c{lime}\c{aqua}\\\c{fuchsia}\c{aqua}\c{blue}$
```

**Ungolf'd:**

```
$$
\def\coloredBox#1{\color{#1}{\rule{5em}{5em}}}
\coloredBox{red}
\coloredBox{yellow}
\coloredBox{fuchsia} \\
\coloredBox{yellow}
\coloredBox{lime}
\coloredBox{aqua}    \\
\coloredBox{fuchsia}
\coloredBox{aqua}
\coloredBox{blue}
$$
```

---

**Edits:**

1. Thanks to [@flawr](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24877/flawr) for pointing out how to fix the colors!
2. Could shave off \$14\,\text{bytes}\$ by replacing `\rule{5em}{5em}` with `▉`, which'd look like$$
   \def\d#1{\color{#1}{▉}}
   \d{red}
   \d{yellow}
   \d{fuchsia} \\
   \d{yellow}
   \d{lime}
   \d{aqua} \\
   \d{fuchsia}
   \d{aqua}
   \d{blue}
   $$

   , but just doesn't look quite the same.
3. Could probably shave off a few more bytes by finding color names that acceptably resemble the intended colors.
4. Just to show what a decently \$\mathrm{\TeX}\text{'d}\$ version of this would look like:$$
   {\newcommand{\rotate}[2]{{\style{transform-origin: center middle; display: inline-block; transform: rotate(#1deg); padding: 50px}{#2}}}}
   {\def\place#1#2#3{\smash{\rlap{\hskip{#1em}\raise{#2em}{#3}}}}}
   {\def\placeBox#1#2#3{\place{#1}{#2}{\color{#3}{\rule{5em}{5em}}}}}
   {\def\placeLabelTop#1#2#3{\place{#1}{#2}{\large{\textbf{#3}}}}}
   {\def\placeLabelLeft#1#2#3{\place{#1}{#2}{\rotate{-90}{\large{\textbf{#3}}}}}}
   \placeLabelTop{1.1}{15.5}{Red}
   \placeLabelTop{5.5}{15.5}{Green}
   \placeLabelTop{11.2}{15.5}{Blue}
   \placeLabelLeft{-6.2}{13.6}{Red}
   \placeLabelLeft{-7.1}{8.5}{Green}
   \placeLabelLeft{-6.5}{3.5}{Blue}
   \placeBox{0}{10}{red}
   \placeBox{5}{10}{yellow}
   \placeBox{10}{10}{fuchsia}
   \placeBox{0}{5}{yellow}
   \placeBox{5}{5}{lime}
   \placeBox{10}{5}{aqua}
   \placeBox{0}{0}{fuchsia}
   \placeBox{5}{0}{aqua}
   \placeBox{10}{0}{blue}
   \place{15.1}{0}{\large{.}}
   \phantom{\rule{15em}{16.5em}}
   $$

Comment: I think your colors are not correct. But apart from that I'd upvote your post if only for the title:)

Comment: @flawr Yeah, they look different than the ones in the question statement, but I figured that if that's how \$\mathrm{\TeX}\$ renders those colors by the names given in the question statement, hopefully it'll be close enough.  =P

Comment: It seems mathjax uses the css color names. So you could replace `purple` with `fuchsia` and `teal` with `aqua` and `green` with `lime` then things would be correct I think.

Comment: Just to note it: The above could be golf'd a bit more by removing some `{}`'s.  But that'd violate too many clean coding principles for my sanity.  =P

Comment: Just note that the PPCG community was never famous for its sanity. If anything probably for the lack thereof.

Comment: @Nat check out the HTML/CSS solution then

Comment: `\rule{5em}{5em}` -> `\rule 5em 5em`

Comment: The `\color{something}` command doesn't take a text argument like `\textcolor{something}{tex to be coloured}`, rather it's a switch, so you can save two bytes by removing the extra pair of braces around `\rule`: `\def\c#1{\color{#1}\rule{5em}{5em}}`. Also, in proper TeX `~` is an active character so you can replace all `\c` by `~` and save a couple more bytes. Don't know about MathJax though.

Answer (score 10):

## Lua + [LÖVE/Love2D](https://love2d.org/), <s>186</s> 183 bytes

```lua
t={[0>1]=0,[0<1]=1}l=love g=l.graphics function l.draw()for i=1,3 do for j=1,3 do g.setColor(t[i<2 or j<2],t[i==2 or j==2],t[i>2 or j>2])g.rectangle('fill',j*10,i*10,10,10)end end end
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/repls/MatureTimelyProgram)

[image]

My first code golf entry!

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice work!

Comment: I think you could use expressions in your truth table: `t={[0>1]=0,[0<1]=1}`.

Comment: @manatwork Smart!

Comment: another löver, nice to see you here

Answer (score 8):

## HTML (GIF), 108 bytes

It's the battle of the web-based image formats! (Any TIF or JPG contenders out there?)

Answer by [@A C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/183315/generate-an-rgb-colour-grid?page=1&tab=votes#comment441323_183338).

```html
<img src=data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAwADAMIGAAAA//8AAP8A/wD/AAD/////AAAAAAAAACwAAAAAAwADAAADBhglNSQEJAA7>
```

---

## HTML (BMP), <s>116</s> 115 bytes

Answer by [@ASCII-only](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/183315/generate-an-rgb-colour-grid?page=1&tab=votes#comment441127_183338).

```html
<img src=data:image/bmp;base64,Qk0+AAAAQVNDTxoAAAAMAAAAAwADAAEAGAD/AP///wD/AAAAAAAA//8A/wD//wAAAAAAAP8A////AP8AAAA>
```

---

## HTML (WebP), 116 bytes

Answer by [@Hohmannfan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/183315/generate-an-rgb-colour-grid/183338?noredirect=1#comment441358_183338).

```html
<img src=data:image/webp;base64,UklGRjYAAABXRUJQVlA4TCoAAAAvAoAAAC8gEEjaH3qN+RcQFPk/2vwHH0QCg0I2kuDYvghLcAoX0f/4Hgc>
```

---

## HTML (PNG), <s>151</s> <s>136</s> 135 bytes

-15 bytes thanks to [@Hohmannfan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/183315/generate-an-rgb-colour-grid/183338?noredirect=1#comment441358_183338).

```html
<img src=data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAADCAIAAADZSiLoAAAAFElEQVR4AWP4z8Dw/z8DEIIodB4A4D0O8pOGuTgAAAAASUVORK5CYII>
```

---

Also, see my [CSS](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/183337/47097) and [SVG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/183461/47097) answers.

Comment: Good idea but.. It seems to me that a 89 bytes file for a 9 pixel image is a bit too much. Maybe manually writing a BMP header can golf this down. If I'm not wrong, the bare minimum header is 26 bytes, plus 12 of actual data (3 rows of 4 pixels) can trim the image down to 38 bytes, which in base64 means 51 or 52 characters rather than 119

Comment: 118: `<img src="data:image/bmp;base64,Qk0+AAAAQVNDTxoAAAAMAAAAAwADAAEAGAD/AP///wD/AAAAAAAA//8A/wD//wAAAAAAAP8A////AP8AAAA=">`. 14 byte file header, 12 byte application header, 9 of actual data per row (+3 to pad to multiple of 4), yeah

Comment: You might be able to strip `/png`, since browsers will detect the file type automatically. FF 66 even allows removal of `image/png`.

Comment: Sorry for stupid question but is this html tag basically creating png? I just ask cause I've asked on s.e. How to make png with html and j.s. And there are other questions on it as well and typical answer was something with urls and what not. I'd like to understand this method.

Comment: @marshalcraft https://stackoverflow.com/q/2807251/4271479

Comment: I haven't counted, but I suspect that `<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAwADAMIGAAAA//8AAP8A/wD/AAD/////AAAAAAAAACwAAAAAAwADAAADBhglNSQEJAA7">` is shorter

Comment: Here's a png file that's 15 bytes smaller when base64 encoded:
`iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAADCAIAAADZSiLoAAAAFElEQVR4AWP4z8Dw/z8DEIIodB4A4D0O8pOGuTgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=`

Comment: To continue the format battle, here's a lossless WebP solution. I can't cut it down anymore without violating the spec, so it narrowly beaten by BMP at 116 bytes.
`<img src=data:image/webp;base64,UklGRjYAAABXRUJQVlA4TCoAAAAvAoAAAC8gEEjaH3qN+RcQFPk/2vwHH0QCg0I2kuDYvghLcAoX0f/4Hgc>`

Comment: @Hohmannfan your solution shows as a broken image for me (Safari)

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart Safari does not support the WebP format: https://caniuse.com/#search=webp

Comment: @Hohmannfan I guess I can blame apple then

Answer (score 8):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 38 bytes

```matlab
image(reshape(de2bi(126973007),3,3,3))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/MzcxPVWjKLU4I7EgVSMl1SgpU8PQyMzS3NjAwFxTxxgENTX//wcA)

Answer (score 7):

### Blockly turtle, 45 blocks

[Try it online!](https://blockly-games.appspot.com/turtle?lang=en&level=10#gtugp7)

How about we play a little game of finding the most ridiculous tool for the job?

Output:

[image: The glorious output of this glorious piece of crappy programming]

The program (as a screenshot for additional heresy):

[image: The program as a screenshot for additional heresy]

Note: The grayed out blocks are also counted towards the metric.

Comment: I’d love that to be a standard PCG challenge! Instead it happens organically on some code golf puzzles

Answer (score 6):

## Node.js, 79 bytes

```js
require('fs').writeFile(a='P',a+[...'3331100110101110010011101011001'].join` `)
```

Produces a file named "P" in the PPM format containing the color grid.

Answer (score 6):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html) (on xterm), 64 bytes

```
Fi16[AP]sF36dD6r31 101dD6rD1[1CP61P[38;5;]Pn[mX]Pz3%0=Fz0<M]dsMx
```

You'll just get a bunch of wacky escape codes instead of colors, but you can still [try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/98t09As2jEgttjN2CzFxazI2FDB0MAQxHIxjDZ0DjAzDIg2trA2tY4NyIvOjYgNqDJWNbB1qzKw8Y1NKfat@P8fAA)

By my understanding, the 16 basic ANSI colors are free to be interpreted however the terminal wants. On the other hand, the 216 colors in the xterm color cube have explicit RGB values. I am using these codes and printing a grid of `X`s:

[image: buncha colorful 'x's]

First we set the input radix to base 15 with `Fi`. This costs two bytes, but gives back three, so... a net gain of a byte (and a big ol' loss in readability). Next we're trying to get our color values onto the stack. In decimal, this would be `21 51 201 51 46 226 201 226 196`, but we're in wacky mode so it's going to be `16 36 D6 36 31 101 D6 101 D1`. We eliminate one of the spaces by slotting in a macro we need to define at some point, `[AP]sF` (which simply prints a line feed). We can shrink `36 D6 36` and `101 D6 101` by placing the first value on the stack, duplicating it, placing the second, and then swapping (`36dD6r`, `101dD6r`).

Macro `M` handles the printing and whatnot. `1CP` prints the escape character. Brackets are used to delimit strings, and as far as I know are not escapable, so we need to print the bracket with an ASCII value as well, `61P`. `[38;5;]P` is the 'set foreground color from the numbered list' code. `n` prints the value from the top of the stack w/o a newline, popping it. `[mX]P` ends the code and prints an 'X'. `z3%0=F` checks the stack depth mod 3, running our line feed macro `F` when necessary. `z0<M` keeps `M` running as long as there's stuff on the stack. `dsMx` to run.

Note that if you run this in dc in an xterm, it'll leave your foreground color blue. `1CP61P74P` (input shown in the screenshot) should reset this.

Answer (score 5):

### C#, <s>248</s> <s>204</s> 198 bytes

```
class P{static void Main(){for(int i=0;i<12;i++){foreach(dynamic n in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor)))if((""+n)[0]=="RYMRYGCRMCBR"[i])Console.BackgroundColor=n;Console.Write(i%4<3?" ":"\n");}}}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

## TI-Basic, x bytes (will score when I can)

Note: content filter is blocking me from looking up the token sizes for each of these commands. If anyone wants to score for me, go for it.

```
TextColor(11
Text(0,0,"0"
TextColor(19
Text(0,2,"0"
Text(2,0,"0"
TextColor(13
Text(4,0,"0"
Text(0,4,"0"
TextColor(14
Text(2,2,"0"
TextColor(18
Text(2,4,"0"
Text(4,2,"0"
TextColor(17
Text(4,4,"0"
```

This look really bad on my little calculator screen. But hey, shape doesn't matter :^)
Golf output:
[image]

Modified for 8x larger output:
[image]

## TI-BASIC, x bytes

Using Pxl-On instead of Text:

```
Pxl-On(0,0,11
Pxl-On(0,1,19
Pxl-On(0,2,13
Pxl-On(1,0,19
Pxl-On(1,1,14
Pxl-On(1,2,18
Pxl-On(2,0,13
Pxl-On(2,1,18
Pxl-On(2,2,17
```

Output:
[image]

Blown up ~11x:
[image]

Comment: It's 180 characters, excluding line breaks.  I'm not sure how/if line breaks are counted in code golf.

Comment: Yes, but TI-BASIC is a tokenized language - for example, the interpreter sees `TextColor` as 2 bytes, not 9 as you would expect @Nat

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
“IỤỵ7ỤĖm8’b4K”P;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwxzPh7uXPNy91RxIHZmWa/GoYWaSifejhrkB1v//AwA)

Niladic link or full program that produces a portable pixmap format image of the desired grid.

Answer (score 4):

### C++, SFML, 177 bytes

```cpp
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int d[]={255,65535,0xFF00FF,65535,65280,0xFFFF00,0xFF00FF,0xFFFF00,0xFF0000};void f(){sf::Image g;g.create(3,3,(sf::Uint8*)d);g.saveToFile("a.jpg");}
```

Uses `sf::Image::create(int,int,unsigned char*)` method to create an image with rgb values in it

Comment: You can shave off one byte by writing `0xFF0000` as `255<<16`.

Comment: Taking it a bit further, you can save 13 bytes by defining the R/G/B colour values in variables before the array: `int b=255<<16,g=65280,r=255,d[]={r,g|r,b|r,g|r,g,b|g,b|r,b|g,b};`

Answer (score 4):

## PostScript, 195 bytes

Output <sub><sup><sub>look closer:</sub></sup></sub> [image]

```
%!PS
/r{rlineto}def/s{newpath moveto 0 1 r 1 0 r 0 -1 r closepath setrgbcolor fill}def
1 0 0 0 2 s
1 1 0 1 2 s
1 0 1 2 2 s
1 1 0 0 1 s
0 1 0 1 1 s
0 1 1 2 1 s
1 0 1 0 0 s
0 1 1 1 0 s
0 0 1 2 0 s
```

To test just paste the code in a blank file and save as `something.ps` and open in a pdf viewer.

To enlarge the output add `50 50 scale` (or some other number) on the second line of the file.

Answer (score 4):

## [x86 Assembly], 42 bytes

```
org 100h
   mov al,13h
   int 10h
   push 40960
   pop es
   xor di,di
   mov bp,8
L: mov eax,[C+bp]
   stosd
   add di,316
   sub bp,4
jnc L

ret
C: dd 00203424h, 0034302ch, 00242c28h
```

[image]

Dump:

```
00000000  B013              mov al,0x13
00000002  CD10              int 0x10
00000004  6800A0            push word 0xa000
00000007  07                pop es
00000008  31FF              xor di,di
0000000A  BD0800            mov bp,0x8
0000000D  668B861E01        mov eax,[bp+0x11e]
00000012  66AB              stosd
00000014  81C73C01          add di,0x13c
00000018  83ED04            sub bp,byte +0x4
0000001B  73F0              jnc 0xd
0000001D  C3                ret
0000001E  0024              add [si],ah
00000020  3420              xor al,0x20
00000022  002C              add [si],ch
00000024  3034              xor [si],dh
00000026  0028              add [bx+si],ch
00000028  2C24              sub al,0x24
```

Comment: Cool answer! Can you post the byte code or xxd dump for this?

Answer (score 4):

### BASIC C64, 106 bytes

```
0 POKE53281,0
1 DATA144,28,158,156,144,13,158,30,159,144,13,156,159,31,144
2 READA:PRINTCHR$(A)+"o";:GOTO2
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### Processing 3: <strike>191</strike> <strike>178</strike> 161 Bytes

```java
int l=0;void setup(){size(33,33);}void draw(){int i=l%33;int j=l/33;stroke((i%3==0||j%3==0)?255:0,(i%3==1||j%3==1)?255:0,(i%3==2||j%3==2)?255:0);point(i,j);l++;}
```

Comment: Since the rectangles are drawn in a for loop, I'm pretty sure you can put them in setup.

Comment: @Razetime i didn't know you could do that I will check that out

Comment: Nice first answer, welcome to the site!

Comment: @Razetime I actually worked out an even better way to do it!

Answer (score 3):

## Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 72 bytes

```
Grid@Partition[RGBColor/@Unitize[Total/@Tuples[IdentityMatrix@3,{2}]],3]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## CSS, <s>147</s> 138 bytes

Uses the `box-shadow` and `background` properties.

```css
html{width:1em;height:1em;background:#f0f;box-shadow:red 0 1em,#ff0 1em 1em,#ff0 0 2em,#0f0 1em 2em,#0ff 2em 2em,#0ff 1em 3em,#00f 2em 3em
```

*-9 bytes ([Gust van de Wal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/183315/generate-an-rgb-colour-grid/183337?noredirect=1#comment441248_183337)):* Make background magenta to cover for two pixels instead of one.

Comment: `html{width:3px;height:3px;background:#f0f;box-shadow:red 0 3px,#ff0 3px 3px,#ff0 0 6px,#0f0 3px 6px,#0ff 6px 6px,#0ff 3px 9px,#00f 6px 9px` for 138 bytes

Comment: To improve visibility, replace `px` with `em` or `mm`. Also, use `html` instead of `body`. Here's the CSS: `html{width:1em;height:1em;background:red;box-shadow:#ff0 1em 0,#f0f 2em 0,#ff0 0 1em,#0f0 1em 1em,#0ff 2em 1em,#f0f 0 2em,#0ff 1em 2em,#00f 2em 2em`

Comment: Just figured that you can make the yellow and cyan shadows bigger and overlap everything: `html{width:2em;height:2em;background:#f0f;box-shadow:red 0 2em,#0f0 2em 4em,#00f 4em 6em,#ff0 1em 3em 0 1em,#0ff 3em 5em 0 1em`, 126 bytes

Answer (score 3):

### CSS, <s>157</s> <s>155</s> <s>147</s> 139 bytes

```css
html{height:100%;background-blend-mode:screen;--:red 33%,#0f0 0 67%,blue 0;background:linear-gradient(90deg,var(--)),linear-gradient(var(--
```

Unlike @darrylyeo's answer no zooming is required (or possible!) I just wanted to show off `background-blend-mode`, despite it being far too long a keyword for code golf. Edit: Saved <s>2</s> 10 bytes with help from @GustvandeWal. Saved a further 8 bytes thanks to @darrylyeo.

Comment: `html` can be replaced with `*` (3 bytes. Will make it a bit ugly) - 
All offset values to some value below 10 (8 bytes. Makes it a LOT more ugly) - 
Last offset value to `0` (2 bytes) - 
`height` to `99%` (1 byte) - 
Omit last closing bracket (1 byte)

Comment: @GustvandeWal I decided against those changes that made the result ugly, but I was able to rearrange my CSS so that I could omit not one but two closing brackets, so thanks for the tip.

Comment: You can still change the last `67%`s to `0`s

Comment: @GustvandeWal Better still, I can change 4 values to `0`s and I'm now tying with @darrylyeo's answer!

Comment: -8 bytes if you use CSS variables! `html{height:100%;background-blend-mode:screen;--:red 33%,#0f0 0 67%,blue 0;background:linear-gradient(90deg,var(--)),linear-gradient(var(--`

Comment: @darrylyeo I had wondered whether there was a way of avoiding the repetition; thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 3):

### [APL (dzaima/APL)](https://github.com/dzaima/APL), <s>186</s> 161 bytes

Uses dzaima's Processing integration.

```apl
G←P5.G
P5.draw←{p←G.pt
G.stroke←'00f'
p 3 3
G.stroke←'0ff'
p 2 3 3 2
G.stroke←'f0f'
p 1 3 3 1
G.stroke←'0f0'
p 2 2
G.stroke←'ff0'
p 1 2 2 1
G.stroke←'f00'
p 1 1}
```

-25 bytes after applying some of dzaima's suggestions and 3 character color codes.

#### Grid (Heavily Magnified):

[image]

#### Actual size:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Raw PPM image, 36 bytes

```
$ xxd image.ppm
00000000: 5036 2033 2033 2031 0a01 0000 0101 0001  P6 3 3 1........
00000010: 0001 0101 0000 0100 0001 0101 0001 0001  ................
00000020: 0100 0001
```

It might not fit the requirements, but it's fun to include anyway as a benchmark.

Comment: Just a reference, use P3 is 62 bytes: `P3 3 3 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1`

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <strike>74</strike> <strike>48</strike> 47 bytes

```
print('\033[9%sm#'*3+'\n')*3%tuple('135326564')
```

Depends on system colors (this assumes 'bright' colors are pure RGB values), but works by modifying the foreground color of `#`s in the terminal.

-26 bytes thanks to xnor

-5 bytes by realizing the color blocks don't need to be rectangles, +4 bytes from miscounting

Comment: You don't need to use loops here, string multiplication suffices: `print('\033[10%sm '*3+'\n')*3%tuple('135326564')`

Comment: @xnor thanks, but it turns out I had to add `\033[0m` before the `\n` because of some interaction with \n coloring the entire next line

Answer (score 2):

**Python Turtle, 202 bytes, inspired by Aaron F's answer**

```
import turtle as m
t=m.Turtle()
t.shape("square")
l=t.left
i=0
y=["#ff0","#f0f","cyan"]
for c in["red"]+y+["#0f0"]+y:t.color(c);t.stamp();a={2:270,5:90}.get(i,0);l(a);t.fd(21);l(a);i+=1
t.color("blue")
```

Comment: Very nice! I was wondering today whether turtle.color() accepted short colour codes :-)

Answer (score 2):

## x86 machine code, 16-bit, MS-DOS, EGA display, <s>40</s> 39 bytes

Hexdump:

```
68 80 b8 07 31 ff be 1e 01 b9 09 00 2e 8a 24 46
b0 db d0 ec ab 73 04 81 c7 9a 00 e2 ef c3 18 1c
1b 1c 14 17 1a 16 02
```

Execution log:

[image: log]

It writes the "bar" character `█` with various attributes to display memory, starting from address `b8800` (display memory starts at `b8000`; I added an offset to move the output to a better place on the screen).

I could use the fact that display memory is filled with space characters, and change their background instead of overwriting them with the bar character, but for best match I needed bright colours, and they are not supported as background.

I developed the code using `debug.com` in a DOS emulator [here](https://www.pcjs.org/devices/pcx86/machine/5170/ega/640kb/rev1/). Source code:

```
; the following should read "push b880" but debug.com cannot emit this instruction
db 68, 80, b8
pop es
xor di, di
mov si, 11e
mov cx, 9
; 10c (loop target)
cs:
mov ah, [si]
inc si
mov al, db
shr ah, 1
stosw
jnc 11b
add di, 9a
; 11b (jump target)
loop 10c
ret
db 18, 1c, 1b, 1c, 14, 17, 1a, 16, 02
```

Answer (score 2):

## GeoGebra Script, 157 bytes

```
Execute[Flatten[Sequence[Sequence[{"P"+i+j+"=("+j*.2+","+i*.2+")","SetColor[P"+i+j+","+(i==2∨j==0)+","+(i==1∨j==1)+","+(i==0∨j==2)+"]"},i,0,2],j,0,2]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/ajmgfrte)

Output:

[image: screenshot of the output]

Answer (score 2):

## Python 123 bytes

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import*;r=0,1,2;imshow([[[2.if i==j==k else 1if(i==k)|(j==k)else 0for k in r]for j in r]for i in r])
```

[image: matplotlib's imshow output]

Seeing no one took advantage of matplotlib in a graphical-output challenge I figured it had to be done for completion.

### Explanation

We can take advantage of the fact that matplotlib will autolevel our colors if we give it floating point data instead of integer data. This means we don't have to worry about specifying specific color values, just the correct ratios. So a red pixel we can define as (2, 0 ,0) and a yellow pixel we can define as (1, 1, 0). All we have to do is make sure at least one of these elements is a float, and matplotlib will automatically scale it to the proper 255-bit color for us.

Ungolfed code for clarity.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
r = (0, 1, 2)
image = [[[0 for i in r] for i in r] for i in r]
for i in r:
    for j in r:
        for k in r:
            if i==j==k: #matching pixel for diagonal element
                image[i][j][k] = 2.
            elif i==k or j==k: #matching pixel for partial component
                image[i][j][k] = 1
imshow(image)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, 229 bytes

```java
import java.awt.*;v->new Frame(){{add(new Panel(){public void paint(Graphics g){var G=(Graphics2D)g;for(int i=9;i-->0;G.fillRect(i%3*4,i/3*4,4,4))G.setColor(new Color(i<4|i==6?255:0,i%2>0|i==4?255:0,i>4|i==2?255:0));}});show();}}
```

Screenshot of the actual 12x12 pixels result:

[image]

Screenshot of the 10 times larger 120x120 pixels result (the `4` in the `fillRect` are replaced with `40`):

[image]

**Explanation:**

```java
import java.awt.*;                // Required import for almost everything
v->                               // Method with empty unused parameter and Frame return
  new Frame(){                    //  Create the Frame
   {                              //   In an inner code-block:
     add(new Panel(){             //    Add a Panel we can draw on:
       public void paint(Graphics g){
                                  //     Overwrite its paint method:
         for(int i=9;i-->0        //      Loop `i` in the range (9,0]:
             ;                    //        After every iteration:
              G.fillRect(i%3*4,i/3*4,4,4))
                                  //         Draw a 4x4 pixel rectangle at coordinate
                                  //         x=i%3*4, y=i//3*4
           G.setColor(new Color(  //       Set the current RGB color to:
             i<4|i==6?255:0,      //        Red: 255 if `i` is 0,1,2,3,6; 0 otherwise
             i%2>0|i==4?255:0,    //        Green: 255 if `i` is 1,3,4,5,7; 0 otherwise
             i>4|i==2?255:0));}});//        Blue: 255 if `i` is 2,5,6,7,8; 0 otherwise
     show();}}                    //    And show the Frame when we're done
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 113 bytes (Ubuntu Terminal)

```ruby
a=[[91,93,95],[93,32,96],[95,96,34]]
for b,c,d in a do puts"\e[#{b}m█\e[0m\e[#{c}m█\e[0m\e[#{d}m█\e[0m" end
```

In Terminal.app, the colors do not display properly:

[image]

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), this program should fit the spec if it's run on Ubuntu, which is the only terminal which has the colors as per specifications. Can someone help me out with this?

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P9E2OtrSUMfSWMfSNFYnGkgbG@lYmoGYpkBax9gkNpYrLb9IIUknWSdFITNPIVEhJV@hoLSkWCkmNVq5Oqk299G0DiDTIBfMT0bjpyD4SgqpeSn//wMA)

Answer (score 1):

## HTML, 150 bytes

```html
<table bgcolor=#0ff><td bgcolor=red><td bgcolor=#ff0><td bgcolor=#f0f><tr><td bgcolor=#ff0><td bgcolor=#0f0><tr><td bgcolor=#f0f><td><td bgcolor=#00f>
```

---

## HTML, 151 bytes

```html
<table bgcolor=#0ff><td bgcolor=#f00><td bgcolor=#ff0><td bgcolor=#f0f><tr><td bgcolor=#ff0><td bgcolor=#0f0><tr><td bgcolor=#f0f><td><td bgcolor=#00f>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 216 bytes

```
l=[41,43,45,43,42,46,45,46,44]
print(''.join(['\033[0;37;'+`l[i+j*3]`+'m \033[0m'+'\n'*(j==2)for i in range(3)for j in range(3)]))
```

Unfortunately, this code does not work well with TIO, but here is a link regardless: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYk5DsMgEAD7vIJuwaDIYTdJYfESjOQUOUD2YiE3eT22SJNmNJpZv9sns611dp4uhtDQtdEaujU/SOG0lsibBDinHFl6GHtE3w94H0BPs486dRgmDYv4nQU0jAydTM5Z9cpFRBFZlAe/nxJbSP8hKFXrDg)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Henry. It might be nice to include a tio.run to execute this code.

Comment: @AJFaraday unfortunately, it doesn't work in TIO, but I will provide a link regardless.

Comment: A language does not need to be in TIO to be allowed. I did mine in Tcl/Tk as so many answers I posted before, and no one was rejected because of your observation.

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript, <s>134</s> <s>131</s> 111 bytes

```js
for(n=0,i=12;--i;)document.write(i%4?'<font color=#'+'f00ff0f0fff00f00fff0f0ff00f'.substr(n++*3,3)+'>█':'<br>')
```

Comment: You can save one byte by using string interpolation for the font tag

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is allowed. `turtle` is a built-in, but it relies on TK, which might not always be available (eg. TIO doesn't like this).

Anyway, it was fun to do. Tried to get it as small as possible while still using Turtle.
(269 bytes because those spaces aren't spaces, they're tabs!)

### Python 2 or 3, 269 bytes

```
import turtle
t=turtle.Turtle()
t.shape("square")
l=t.left
i=0
y=["yellow","magenta","cyan"]
for c in ["red"]+y+["green"]+y+["blue"]:
    i+=1
    t.color(c)
    t.stamp()
    if i==9:
        break
    elif i%3==0:
        a=90 if i==6 else 270
    else:
        t.fd(21)
        continue
    l(a)
    t.fd(21)
    l(a)
```

Comment: I’m not that hot on the rules of code golf, but that seems fine to me. And I love that you did it this way :)

Comment: A language does not need to be in TIO to be allowed. I did mine in Tcl/Tk as so many answers I posted before, and no one was rejected because of your observation.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 25 bytes

```
.wm.eXbk;mX*3]Zd=k255G=G3
```

The online interpreter doesn't show generated images, so this program must be run locally. It generates a 3x3 pixel image like the one in the question.

Answer (score 1):

## SVG, 212 bytes

Uses the CSS property `mix-blend-mode: lighten`.

```html
<svg><g fill=red><path d="M0 0h3v1H0z"/><path d="M0 0h1v3H0z"/><g fill=lime><path d="M0 1h3v1H0z"/><path d="M1 0h1v3H1z"/><g fill=blue><path d="M0 2h3v1H0z"/><path d="M2 0h1v3H2z"/><style>*{mix-blend-mode:lighten
```

---

## SVG, <s>276</s> 240 bytes

Previous answer using `<rect>` instead of `<path>`.

```html
<svg><g fill=red><rect width=3 height=1 /><rect width=1 height=3 /><g fill=lime><rect width=3 height=1 y=1 /><rect width=1 height=3 x=1 /><g fill=blue><rect width=3 height=1 y=2 /><rect width=1 height=3 x=2 /><style>*{mix-blend-mode:lighten
```

Answer (score 1):

## Processing, <s>225</s> 210 chars/bytes

Exhilarating code, I know.

```
fill(#FF0000);
rect(0,0,4,4);
fill(#FFFF00);
rect(0,4,4,4);
rect(4,0,4,4);
fill(#FF00FF);
rect(0,8,4,4);
rect(8,0,4,4);
fill(#00FF00);
rect(4,4,4,4);
fill(#00FFFF);
rect(4,8,4,4);
rect(8,4,4,4);
fill(#0000FF);
rect(8,8,4,4);
```

[image]

Comment: Unless there is something magic about 30 & 60, change to single-digit values (e.g., 4, 8 would give you the maximum) and that will save you 7 bytes.

Comment: Actually, with a=3 instead of 30, get rid of a altogether and just hardcode the 3s and remove the first line = 9 more bytes.

Comment: @manassehkatz Was able to save 15 bytes. The 30 and 60 were mainly to make the image big enough, which isn't necessary for the challenge. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby with [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com/), 89 characters

```ruby
Shoes.app{n=0..2
n.map{|i|n.map{|j|fill n.map{|e|i==e||j==e ?:F:0}*''
rect i*9,j*9,9,9}}}
```

Sample output:

[image: Shoes window screenshot with RGB color grid]

Comment: If you leave out *9 and change the other 9s to 1s, will that give 1-pixel color squares? If so, that will save 4 bytes. But if that would result in "borders without insides" then leave it as is.

Comment: @manassehkatz, unfortunately that would result only borders. `nostroke` would turn off the borders and the filled rectangles would appear, but not with the desired colors as kind of antialiasing would be performed on the rectangles' margins. `strokewidth 0` would solve that, but would exceed the 4 characters gain. :(

Answer (score 1):

## [C64 Assembly], 58 bytes

Machine code:

```
01 08 0b 08 e3 07 9e 32 30 35 39 20 a2 03 ca
a9 a0 9d 20 04 9d 28 04 9d 50 04 bd 30 08 9d
20 d8 bd 33 08 9d 28 d8 bd 36 08 9d 50 d8 d0
e0 4c 2d 08 02 07 04 07 05 03 04 03 06
```

Assembly code:

```
*=$0801
    .word (+), 2019     ;line number
    .null $9e, ^+       ;sys <start>
+
    ldx #$03
    loop:
        dex
        lda #$a0    
        sta $0400,x
        sta $0428,x
        sta $0450,x

        lda tabcol+0,x
        sta $d800,x
        lda tabcol+3,x
        sta $d828,x
        lda tabcol+6,x
        sta $d850,x
    bne loop
    jmp *

tabcol:
.byte $02,$07,$04,$07,$05,$03,$04,$03,$06
```

[image]

Comment: I have a feeling it might be possible to reduce it even further with some self-modifying code and/or using Indirect-indexed addressing. Also if its smaller to fit zeropage address: $7c - ? also the sys loading bytes can be stripped.

Answer (score 1):

## [PostScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript), <s>77</s> <s>61</s> 60 bytes

Code:

```postscript
3 3 1[.1 0 0 .1 0 0]<AC80C9809A8>false 3 colorimage showpage
```

Result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

## Racket (BSL + 2htdp/image), 152 bytes

```
(define(s q)(star 9 'solid q))(above(beside(s 'red)(s 'yellow)(s 'magenta))(beside(s 'yellow)(s 'green)(s 'cyan))(beside(s 'magenta)(s 'cyan)(s 'blue)))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (s q) (star 9 'solid q))
(above
 (beside (s 'red) (s 'yellow) (s 'magenta))
 (beside (s 'yellow) (s 'green) (s 'cyan))
 (beside (s 'magenta) (s 'cyan) (s 'blue)))
```

[image: color grid]

`star` was the shortest shape. Overall a pretty boring answer. I'll try to come up with a more interesting one when time permits.

Answer (score 1):

## Tcl/Tk, 208 bytes

```
gri [can .c]
proc O {x y z w C\ #FF0} {.c cr o $x $y $z $w -f $C}
O 2 2 5 5 red
O 8 2 11 5
O 14 2 17 5 #F0F
O 2 8 5 11
O 8 8 11 11 #0F0
O 14 8 17 11 #0FF
O 2 14 5 17 #F0F
O 8 14 11 17 #0FF
O 14 14 17 17 #00F
```

Notes:

- There is an Enter on bottom
- Ran in interactive shell to have commands' abbreviations enabled by default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript + HTML Canvas, 153 bytes

```js
c=c.getContext`2d`;for(i=0;i<9;i++){x=i/3|0;y=i%3;c.fillStyle=`rgb(${(!x|!y)*255},${(x==1|y==1)*255},${(x>1|y>1)*255})`;c.fillRect(x,y,1,1)}
```

```html
<canvas id=c>
```